# EF4.1 Model with complex type with Primary Key as string not working well

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I have the following two models

```
[DataContract]
public class Event
{       
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Place Place { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class Place
{
    [Key]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and data context class:

```
public class myDB: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Place> Places { get; set; }
}
```

I run the following code for example

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Foo();
    }

    private void Foo()
    {
        var db = new myDB();

        var place = new Place
                        {
                            ID = "{59E0F90C-03DB-453C-8C9E-4747957ED37E}",
                            Name = "Home",
                        };

        db.Places.Add(place);
        db.SaveChanges();

        var @event = new Event
        {
            Name = "Test",
            Place = place,
            TimeFrame = new TimeFrame() {StartTime = DateTime.Now, EndTime = DateTime.Now }
        };
        db.Events.Add(@event);
        db.SaveChanges();
        var eventIndex = @event.ID;

        var ev = db.Events.Find(@eventIndex);
        var evPlace = ev.Place;

        var pl = db.Places.Find("{59E0F90C-03DB-453C-8C9E-4747957ED37E}");
    }
```

everything works fine and evPlace is the object I just added to db, pl is also not null.

But when I try to run the following code from the controller where 5 is the ID of the new event object

```
var ev = _db.Events.Find(5);
var evPlace = ev.Place;

var pl = _db.Places.Find("{59E0F90C-03DB-453C-8C9E-4747957ED37E}");
```

pl and ev are not null but ev.Place is null (evPlace)

Any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with the primary key being a `string` or not. Generally Entity Framework doesn't load navigation properties automatically. You need to specify that explicitly:

```
var ev = db.Events.Include(e => e.Place).SingleOrDefault(e => e.ID == 5);
```

Or: If you declare the `Place` property as `virtual`...

```
public virtual Place Place { get; set; }
```

...EF will enable *lazy loading* for this property and load the `Place` from the database as soon as you access it in your code. Your code example would work then. Be aware that lazy loading leads to a second query/roundtrip to the database whereas eager loading (`Include`) loads both the event and the place in a single query.

More about loading related entities is [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/31/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-6-loading-related-entities.aspx).